# ufw not blocking openvpn connection

Tags: openvpn, ufw

I have a private server that runs Ubuntu 20.04. I have installed ufw and I suppose I get the basics.

Last week I have installed a wireguard server. I was able to block the connections to wireguard port from ufw. Now I have installed OpenVPN with this installer https://github.com/angristan/openvpn-install.

The script is pretty basic, I was able to create clients and connect to VPN from my mobile phone. But the weird thing is I can't deny or reject on the OpenVPN port.

Previously on other services (e.g. mongo, MySQL...) I needed to add specific rules to access the ports. But this one I was able to connect directly and there is no new rules on ufw. Also even though I added new rules to deny/reject on default port and my custom port, I still can access it.

I feel like I am missing something that can cause a vulnerability on the system.

Comment: Maybe you added rules for TCP, but you use UDP for the VPN? (`proto udp` in your .ovpn file). Or give more info about your setup (`iptables-save`, `ip a`, ...)

Comment: What port are you using for openvpn? Openvpn can use basically any port you set it to. A common method of circumventing the firewall is to use port 443 or port 80 as these are already open.

Comment: I am using port 62000 for my OpenVPN setup. I have added deny rules for both 1194 and 62000 ports on both protocols; tcp and udp. 
I am currently back to wireguard since it became too complicated for me to solve it in the short term. I am guessing it won't be as simple as adding a new rule to ufw, I started checking iptables but I am a novice on these topics so it is on hold for me.

As a first step; I want to be able to block (also know which port so I can monitor the traffic too) the openvpn

Comment: please provide output of `netstat -nlput`

Answer (score 0):

I was also curious about this (and stumbled on this question), so I took a look at the script.

The script uses iptables to set up firewall rules to handle packets that come into OpenVPN. This includes opening the port you chose:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i $NIC -p $PROTOCOL --dport $PORT -j ACCEPT"
```

These iptables rules are stored in a script called 'add-openvpn-rules.sh,' which is run every time the service starts.

```
ExecStart=/etc/iptables/add-openvpn-rules.sh
```

The inverse rule is stored in a file called rm-openvpn-rules.sh, which is run every time you stop the service to remove the rule.

You can verify that the rules reflect your choices by running`cat /etc/iptables/add-openvpn-rules.sh`, and you can see them in your iptables ruleset by scanning through the output of `iptables-save` (or searching for your selected port).

Since UFW also creates iptables rules, I would imagine that, depending on the order that the rules are created, you'd see different behavior. I don't, unfortunately, know how conflicting iptables rules are handled.

At the very least we can see why the packets are being allowed (the script explicitly creates firewall rules in iptables). How those rules interact with the rules we create in UFW, I'll leave to an iptables expert.

Comment: Woow. It has been some time over this. If I remember correct, the issue was resolved after a reinstall. But thanks for a detailed analysis